# Problemas al subir repositorio en GitHub

Tags: php, github, laravel-6

El problema que tengo es que yo subo un repositorio a github y este sube normal. pero cuando descargo el proyecto y lo corro sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cabe resaltar que antes de correr este proyecto yo ejecuto los comndos de

```
composer install
npm install
```

ya que la carpeta vendor y node_modules no se sube

esto es lo que sale en el log

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el log que está dentro de storage se debió grabar el error generado, lo puedes agregar?

Comment: arriba deje lo que sale en el log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando clonas en local un repositorio con una aplicación Laravel de *Github*, *Bitbucket* o similar hay una [serie de pasos comunes que hay que realizar](https://github.com/oricis/notes/blob/master/contents/laravel/laravel-run-from-repo.md).

Inicialmente no tienes (o no debes de tener) fichero `.env` necesitarás uno para almacenar la `APP_KEY`, datos de acceso a BD, etc.

Si estas en una máquina con *Linux* necesitas asignar además algunos permisos a ciertos directorios y puede que a todos los ficheros si la aplicación se desarrollo en Windows, por ejemplo. En ese caso te recomiendo revisar el contenido del enlace que he puesto.

**A *groso modo*, los pasos serían:**

1.Instalar las dependencias

```
composer install
```

2.Crear el fichero `.env`:

```
cp .env.example .env
```

y configurar los datos de acceso a la BD.

3.Generar la clave de la app:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

4.Crear la BD. Usando la consola o el programa que uses para gestionarlas (phpMyAdmin, MysqlWorkbench, etc).

5.Ejecutar migraciones:

```
php artisan migrate
```

6.Sembrar las tablas (posiblemente, si tienes datos por defecto como un listado de regiones, paises, etc).

```
php artisan db:seed
```

***NOTA:*** los pasos descritos son genéricos, puede que necesites crear directorios o añadir otros ficheros para arrancar la aplicación. Si seguiste los pasos y no funciona revisa el `.gitignore` para ver que es lo que puede faltar.